How to pass refs to lazy load components
Hello guys I'm trying to pass refs to lazy load component but getting null instead of {current: null} please check where I'm doing mistake.
'use client';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useRef } from 'react';
const Component = dynamic(() => import('../components/Component'), {
  ssr: false,
});

export default function Home() {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  return <Component ref={ref} />;
}


import { forwardRef, useEffect } from 'react';
const Component = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref);
  }, []);
  return <h1>Practice</h1>;
});
export default Component; 

I'm expecting {current: null} this output in Component

The issue you're encountering arises because the ref is not being forwarded correctly to the lazy-loaded component. In React, when you use forwardRef, the ref is correctly passed to the component, but with dynamic imports, it requires special handling.
To ensure the ref is correctly forwarded, you can make the following adjustments:

Ensure that the component is wrapped with forwardRef and that the ref is being passed down properly:

import { forwardRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Component = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref);
  }, [ref]); // Ensure ref is included in the dependency array

  return <h1>Practice</h1>;
});

export default Component;


When using dynamic from Next.js, you need to ensure that the dynamic import correctly handles the ref forwarding. To do this, use a wrapper to apply forwardRef around the lazy-loaded component:

'use client';
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { useRef } from 'react';

const DynamicComponent = dynamic(
  () => import('../components/Component').then(mod => mod.default),
  { ssr: false }
);

export default function Home() {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return <DynamicComponent ref={ref} />;
}

In this setup, the ref should correctly pass through and be logged as { current: null } when the component mounts.

I tried it but it is not working
